# flex, multi request from the command class, how to differentiate each response from results in command

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I run into a question that asked by a flex interviewer:
If there are 2 requests from the command class, and when back end process the request, they may take different time(the first command may take longer time to process so that it returns after the response of the second request).so, in your result-handler of your  how do you know which response is for which request?

Note: they are in the same command, and they are processed by the same result handler.

Comment: i would add something to the result (that back end returns) to signify which process it represents.

Comment: Ah, that's a classic: use [AsyncToken](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AsyncToken.html)